# How to explain the peak frequency and resistance relationship in this op amp circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, resistance, frequency-response

I was studying [thid](http://simonbramble.co.uk/lt_spice/ltspice_lt_spice_tutorial_2.htm) tutorial by Simon Bramble.

I changed the original circuit a little bit and this is the subject of our discussion:

[image: op amp circuit required for context]

As you see, R1, R2 and R3 are all 1kOhm.

When I run an AC analysis, this is db/Hz curve:

[image: frequency response required for context]

The peak of the solid green line is exactly at 1KHz.

I will name this frequency where the solid green line peaks as "peak frequency."

Now, when I change R (R=R1=R2=R3) from 1k to some other value, this relationship emerges:

[image: observation]

To be more verbose:

- When R = 1k: same curve but shifted horizontally to peak frequency = 1k
- When R = 10k: same curve but shifted horizontally to peak frequency = 100
- When R = 100: same curve but shifted horizontally to peak frequency = 10k

So we observe this formula $$R \cdot f = 10^6$$

This holds for arbitrary R and f values as well: like R = 500, peak frequency = 2k

I do not know how this formula emerges. Could you explain me (preferable ELI5, but any clue/tip is appreciated too) the reason behind this observation?

Extra for Andy aka:
When I remove R3 from the circuit, behavior changes radically:

[image: without R3]

Extra related to Bimpelrekkie's comment:

He was apparently right about RC product affecting the frequency. What I have observed when changing C1 and C2 is in line with his comment. Here it is for record: (in the circuit with R3)

- When C1=112nF & C2 = 224nF: same curve but peak frequency = 1kHz
- When C1=224nF & C2 = 448nF: same curve but peak frequency = 500Hz
- When C1=56n & C2 = 112n: same curve but peak frequency = 2kHz

These observations and Bimpelrekkie's comment may be restated here:

$$f \propto \frac{1}{RC}$$

(This only holds when C2 = 2*C1, if I change their ratio, the curve changes both amplitude and frequency so it becomes weirder.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109413/discussion-on-question-by-alpersunter-how-to-explain-peak-frequency-and-resistan).

Comment: @VoltageSpike I understand the rule about use of comments. But the chat unfortunately does not support latex rendering. What should one do in such a case?

Comment: Write a good answer, I guess that's why they want us to move comments

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am trying to analyze the following circuit (assuming an ideal [opamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier)):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD6i9c.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_3=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\text{I}_5\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_5
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\frac{\text{V}_\text{o}-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{o}-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{o}-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, Using an [ideal opamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Ideal_op_amps), We know that \$\text{V}_x:=\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-=\text{V}_2=\text{V}_3\$. So we can rewrite equation \$(3)\$ as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_3}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_x-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_3}=\frac{\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_x-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{o}-\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_4}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{o}-\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_5}
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

Now, we can solve for the transfer function:

$$\mathcal{H}:=\frac{\text{V}_\text{o}}{\text{V}_\text{i}}=\frac{\text{R}_2\text{R}_4-\text{R}_3\text{R}_5}{\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)+\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}\tag5$$

---

Now, applying this to your circuit we need to use (from now on I use the lower case letters for the function in the 'complex' s-domain where I used [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)):

- $$\text{R}_2=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}\tag6$$
- $$\text{R}_4=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}\tag7$$

So, the transfer function becomes:

$$\mathcal{h}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{v}_\text{o}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}-\text{R}_3\text{R}_5}{\text{R}_1\left(\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}+\text{R}_3\right)+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}\left(\text{R}_3+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}\right)}=$$
$$\frac{1-\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_3\text{R}_5\text{s}^2}{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_1\text{R}_3\text{s}^2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_3\right)\text{s}+1}\tag8$$

Because we are working with sinusodial signals, [we can write](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Why_is_it_assumed_Zejw_and_Sjw) \$\text{s}=\text{j}\omega\$ [where](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit) \$\text{j}^2=-1\$ and \$\omega=2\pi\text{f}\$ with \$\text{f}\$ is the [frequency in Hertz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency). So, we can write:

$$\underline{\mathcal{h}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)=\frac{\underline{\text{v}}_\text{o}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)}{\underline{\text{v}}_\text{i}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)}=\frac{1-\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_3\text{R}_5\left(\text{j}\omega\right)^2}{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_1\text{R}_3\left(\text{j}\omega\right)^2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_3\right)\left(\text{j}\omega\right)+1}=$$
$$\frac{1+\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_3\text{R}_5\omega^2}{1-\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_1\text{R}_3\omega^2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_3\right)\omega\text{j}}\tag9$$

Now, we can find the amplitude by finding the [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Complex_numbers) of \$(9)\$:

$$\left|\underline{\mathcal{h}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{1+\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_3\text{R}_5\omega^2}{\sqrt{\left(1-\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_1\text{R}_3\omega^2\right)^2+\left(\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_3\right)\omega\right)^2}}\tag{10}$$

When we want to find where the peak frequency is, we need to find:

$$\frac{\partial\left|\underline{\mathcal{h}}\left(\text{j}\hat{\omega}\right)\right|}{\partial\hat{\omega}}=0\space\Longrightarrow\space\hat{\omega}=\dots\tag{11}$$

---

When \$\text{R}:=\text{R}_1=\text{R}_3=\text{R}_5\$ we get the following transfer function (see \$(10)\$):

$$\left|\underline{\mathcal{h}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{1+\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}^2\omega^2}{\sqrt{\left(1-\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}^2\omega^2\right)^2+\left(2\text{C}_2\text{R}\omega\right)^2}}\tag{12}$$

When we want to find where the peak frequency is, we get:

$$\frac{\partial\left|\underline{\mathcal{h}}\left(\text{j}\hat{\omega}\right)\right|}{\partial\hat{\omega}}=0\space\Longrightarrow\space\hat{\omega}=\frac{1}{\text{R}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2}}\tag{13}$$

So, for the frequency we get:

$$\hat{\omega}=2\pi\hat{\text{f}}=\frac{1}{\text{R}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2}}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\hat{\text{f}}=\frac{1}{2\pi\text{R}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2}}\tag{14}$$

So, we get:

1. When \$\text{C}_1=224\cdot10^{-9}\space\text{F}\$,\$\text{C}_1=112\cdot10^{-9}\space\text{F}\$, and \$\text{R}=1000\space\Omega\$:
   $$\hat{\text{f}}=\frac{1}{2\pi\cdot1000}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{224\cdot10^{-9}\cdot112\cdot10^{-9}}}=\frac{15625 \sqrt{2}}{7 \pi }\approx1004.817\space\text{Hz}\tag{15}$$
2. When \$\text{C}_1=224\cdot10^{-9}\space\text{F}\$,\$\text{C}_1=112\cdot10^{-9}\space\text{F}\$, and \$\text{R}=10000\space\Omega\$:
   $$\hat{\text{f}}=\frac{1}{2\pi\cdot10000}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{224\cdot10^{-9}\cdot112\cdot10^{-9}}}=\frac{3125}{7 \sqrt{2} \pi }\approx100.482\space\text{Hz}\tag{16}$$
3. When \$\text{C}_1=224\cdot10^{-9}\space\text{F}\$,\$\text{C}_1=112\cdot10^{-9}\space\text{F}\$, and \$\text{R}=100000\space\Omega\$:
   $$\hat{\text{f}}=\frac{1}{2\pi\cdot100000}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{224\cdot10^{-9}\cdot112\cdot10^{-9}}}=\frac{625}{14 \sqrt{2} \pi }\approx10.048\space\text{Hz}\tag{17}$$

**EDIT:**

Also notice that when \$\text{C}_1=224\cdot10^{-9}\space\text{F}\$ and \$\text{C}_1=112\cdot10^{-9}\space\text{F}\$, we have:

$$\hat{\text{f}}=\frac{1}{2\pi\text{R}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{224\cdot10^{-9}\cdot112\cdot10^{-9}}}=$$
$$\frac{1}{\text{R}}\cdot\frac{15625000 \sqrt{2}}{7 \pi }\approx1.004817317139628\cdot10^6\cdot\frac{1}{\text{R}}\tag{18}$$

So, when we multiply both sides by \$\text{R}\$, we get:

$$\hat{\text{f}}\cdot\text{R}=\frac{15625000 \sqrt{2}}{7 \pi }\approx1.004817317139628\cdot10^6\approx10^6\tag{19}$$

Comment: I edited my answer, about your peak frequencies because they're not exactly what you wrote in your question.